# Closing a "Pop-Up like" activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, popupwindow

I made this app, it gives notification to user. Notification is just a string. Sometimes a string can be long so I tried to show that string in a pop-up layout.

Like this, my xml:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.dot.Popup"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    </activity>
```

My layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#aeb25e" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notif"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="asd"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#1D331C"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

And the code:

```
public class Popup extends Activity {

String notif;
Intent sender;
TextView popup_notif;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.popup);

    sender=getIntent();
    notif=sender.getExtras().getString("notif_ana");

    popup_notif = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notif);
    popup_notif.setText(notif);
}
```

}

So here is my problem, I can display first item of string array (notifications), when second notification comes and I click, I display the previous screen. How can I refresh the string array, or kill the activity to call next string array, etc?

Thanks I hope I explanied good enough.

Comment: Post the code you use to create the `Notification`

Answer (score 0):

To close Activity you need to call `finish()`. And instead of activity i'd use rather Toast (with perhaps custom layout) or one of numerous libraries providing toast alterantives. Using activity here may be slightly overkill

Comment: finish() is not the solution on this, if I use it, then I cannot open the layout. I will check that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try getting the intent and extras in the onResume() function and update the TextView in onResume() function of the activity.

```
public class Popup extends Activity {

    String notif;
    Intent sender;
    TextView popup_notif;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.popup);
        popup_notif = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.notif);    
    }
    @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
        sender=getIntent();
        notif=sender.getExtras().getString("notif_ana");
        popup_notif.setText(notif);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Nope. It didn't help. Thank you.